# Ajax autocomplete issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am working on getting an autocomplete from a remote data source. It is return JSON but it doesn't populate the autocomplete box.

```
$( "#patientName").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/cs/accountTypeAhead",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { "patientName": $("#patientName").val(),
                                     "requestID": (new Date()).getTime()},
            success: function( data ) {
                var searchInfo = new Array();   

                for(var key in data) 
                {

                    if(typeof data[key] === "object") {
                        for(var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) 
                        {
                            searchInfo.push(data[key]);

                        }//end for loop
                    }//end if 


                    else if(key == "requestID") 
                    {
                        if (data.requestID < $("#requestID").val() )
                        { return false;}

                        else
                        {
                            $("#requestID").val(data.requestID);
                        }
                    }//end if/else


                }//end for loop


                return  searchInfo; 
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
});
```

My output from console is what I was expecting. I think it has something to due with returning the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
return  searchInfo;
```

by

```
response(searchInfo);
```

Comment: Then how do you get the value out? It is returning the correct value. Then you look at the examples on [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html) it is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working version of "success" handler for autocomplete using remote JSON .

```
success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item){
return { label: item.FirstName, value: item.FirstName, id:item.MemberId }

}))
                        }
```

Hope this helps.

Also, have a look at this demonstration. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ultimately the solution was

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help the solution was

```
success: function (data) {
       response($.map(data.results, function (item){
       return { label: item, value: item };
   }));
}
```